# Form input textarea vertical-align not working

Tags: html, css, textarea, vertical-alignment

I'm struggling to get inputted text to align with the top of an input textarea, on an HTML form, and have searched forums extensively, so I thought I'd post here.

I've tried using:

```
textarea{
vertical-align:top;}
```

and

```
input["textarea"]{
vertical-align:top;}
```

I've also tried adding `autoflow:auto`;

Comment: Isn't that what it already does?

Comment: `overflow: auto` not `autoflow:auto;`

Comment: @Paul Please explain more what you're trying to achieve and share a fiddle of what you have done so far.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are wanting to use a `<textarea>` instead of an `<input>`. [Here's some background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637326/why-isnt-textarea-an-inputtype-textarea) for you too, but you use different form elements for different things.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="input" value="input">
<br />
<textarea rows="10">Textarea that has text aligned to the top. No css needed</textarea>
```

**[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/u8r7F/)**

Comment: How can you tell this is what op is trying to ask?

Comment: My best guess by his CSS selection `input[type="textarea"]`.

Comment: that's exactly what it is - can't believe you just answered this so quickly, thanks so much

Comment: I don't now how he could tell, but it's what I was trying to ask too.  For some reason, `<input type="textarea"> ` wouldn't word wrap and vertically centered the text, ignoring the rows attribute and the wrap attribute.  Changing to `<textarea>` solved the problem.  Old post, but problem seems up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what your issue is but I will try and give an answer to what I believe is your problem :)

When you do like this:

```
<form>
    <textarea cols="25" rows="5" required>

    </textarea>
</form>
```

The spaces between your textarea is already rendered when you run the code - this means that when you wanna type in the textarea there is 100 different places you can begin texting.

I think what you wanna do is this:

```
<form>
    <textarea cols="25" rows="5" required></textarea>
</form>
```

This way the texting in the textarea will begin in the top-left corner of the textarea, that is because you have not rendered any lines when you run this code.

**DEMO** of the two Versions:
http://jsfiddle.net/2thMQ/4/