# textarea html tag not taking space between words

Tags: textarea

I have a contact form with standard input fields, in which all fields working well but when i try to put something in message box (textarea input tag ) it is not taking space between two words..

Comment: Can you add some code? Can you explain it more in detail? Can you update this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/empie/W34SQ/

Comment: Also there is no such thing as an input tag for textarea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637326/why-isnt-textarea-an-inputtype-textarea

Comment: thanks for reply my textarea code is given below <textarea id="msg" rows="5" cols="40" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea> http://panacheheights.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file `mb.bgndGallery.js`, there is the following function:

```
keyboard:function(el){
            $(document).on("keydown.bgndGallery",function(e){
                switch(e.keyCode){
                    case 32:
                        if(el.opt.paused){
                            $.mbBgndGallery.play(el);
                            el.opt.paused=false;
                        }else{
                            el.opt.paused=true;
                            $.mbBgndGallery.pause(el);
                        }
                        e.preventDefault();
                        break;
     }
  });
}
```

Keystroke '32' is representing the 'spacebar' and this one is causing troubles. You either remove this case or disable the keyboard functionality of this plugin (at the top of the file).

```
$.mbBgndGallery ={
        name:"mb.bgndGallery",
        author:"Matteo Bicocchi",
        version:"1.8.0",
        defaults:{
            activateKeyboard:false

        }
```