# Textarea as input

Tags: html, css

I get that textarea [is its own element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6180995/817379) and not an input type, but how can I convert

```
<input type="text"
    class="media_url"
    name="media[image_url][]"
    value=""
/>
```

to use textarea instead? Or is there a better way to have a text input field display as a different height and have the text wrap and not be middle vertically aligned?

Comment: no. text inputs are inherently single-line fields. You can change their height via css, but you canNOT change them to become multi-line. That's why there's textareas.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? How to use a `textarea`? Any reason why you want to use `input`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<textarea
    class="media_url"
    name="media[image_url][]"
></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <textarea name="media[image_url][]" class="media_url" rows="40" cols="10"> 
</textarea>
```