# Why isn't <textarea> self closing?

Tags: html, w3c

I've been wondering why none of the revisions to the HTML specification have ever made `textarea` able to be self-closing. [Lot's of SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637326/why-isnt-textarea-an-inputtype-textarea) have answered why it is a separate tag from `input`, and it makes sense to me that they'd want to preserve it as a separate tag for compatibility, but why wouldn't they make `<textarea />` just as valid as `<textarea></textarea>` since this wouldn't break anything as far as I can tell.

Comment: Quote: *"this wouldn't break anything"* ~ It would.  Because `<textarea></textarea>` is a container and `<textarea />` is not.  `<textarea>here are the contents of the text area box.</textarea>`

Comment: Exactly the same reason as for `script` elements: [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/69913/1529630)

Answer (score 10):

Because `<input />` can't work like container for text, While `<textarea> text goes here</textarea>` can work as container for default text!

Here is what explain your curiosity about why they choose to go this way.

```css
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Easy way for default input text -->
<textarea>Here is why because text can be input into box like paragraph tag</textarea>
```