# Adding <textarea> to my form causes all proceeding html to go inside text field, but I need multiple lines of text

Tags: forms, textarea

I created a form sign up. I replaced  with  to create multiple lines of text in a form field, which works, but now it breaks my site by adding all html that follows on my page INSIDE the box.

If you reproduce the code below, you'll see that the close paragraph code is added INSIDE the text box.

I want this to stop happening.

```html
<p>
    <textarea id="fieldEvent" name="cm-event" placeholder="Which event are you most looking forward to?" type="text" />
</p>
```

Comment: Textarea isn't [self closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729059/why-isnt-textarea-self-closing)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @tkausl

For anyone looking for the answer to the same problem, you need to close the textarea tag *after* the code but before the closing paragraph tag.

So that it will look like this:

```html
<p>
    <textarea id="fieldEvent" name="cm-event" placeholder="Which event are you most looking forward to?" type="text" /></textarea>
</p>
```

Comment: Ending a tag with `/` is only for self closing tags, as mentioned above. Since the `textarea` is not a self closing tag, you should remove the `/` from the opening `textarea` so that your code is: `<textarea id="fieldEvent" name="cm-event" placeholder="Which event are you most looking forward to?" type="text"></textarea>`