# How to make input field's height responsive to the content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

It is a MERN stack app. I tried to make the height of a textarea responsive to the content using [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize/25621277?noredirect=1#answer-25621277).

It looks like the external javascript file is working because I tried putting `alert` in the for loop and it did work. So I tried putting alert inside the `OnInput()` function but the `alert` was not called. Therefore, I think something is wrong with this function.

**index.html**

```
<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <script src="/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

**main.js**

```
var tx = document.getElementsByClassName('comment-area-responsive');

for (var i = 0; i < tx.length + 1; i++) {
  //   alert(i);
  tx[i].setAttribute(
    'style',
    'height:' + tx[i].scrollHeight + 'px;overflow-y:hidden;'
  );
  tx[i].addEventListener('change', OnInput, false);
}

function OnInput() {
  this.style.height = 'auto';
  alert('hi2');
  this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

**page**

```
<textarea 
  className='comment-area-responsive' 
  name='title' 
  placeholder='What do you think?' 
  value={text} onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)} 
  required
/>
```

Comment: You may have called your function `OnInput`, but the event you are binding it to is the `change` event. That one fires only after the field loses focus again, not _while_ the user is typing.

Comment: I wrote a codepen long ago to change the font-size of a textarea when there is too much text, not exacly the same thing but could help: https://codepen.io/elisabeth_hamel/pen/pdLRvv
I used the keyup event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script works as intended after removing a few problems from your code -

1. Instead of `change` event, you should listen to the textarea's `input` event.
2. `textarea` is a container, so you close it using a closing tag `</textarea>` and not a self closing tag. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729059/why-isnt-textarea-self-closing)
3. Maybe you're using some other library, so make sure that you really need `value={text}` and `onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}` attributes on the textarea. If you added them only for the purpose of this script, then they're not needed as you can see in the code below.

Run the snippet below to check that it works correctly after fixing all the above problems

```js
var tx = document.getElementsByClassName('comment-area-responsive');
for (var i = 0; i < tx.length; i++) {
  tx[i].setAttribute('style', 'height:' + (tx[i].scrollHeight) + 'px;overflow-y:hidden;');
  tx[i].addEventListener("input", OnInput, false);
}

function OnInput() {
  this.style.height = 'auto';
  this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px';
}
```

```html
<div>
<textarea 
  class='comment-area-responsive' 
  name='title' 
  placeholder='What do you think?'  
  required
  ></textarea>  
</div>
```

**Update** :  For getting it to work with React, since React treats `onChange` and `onInput` in the same way, you can do it **inside your `onChange` handler**, like -

```
const setText = (val) => {
      this.setState({text: val});
      var tx = document.getElementsByClassName('comment-area-responsive');
      for (var i = 0; i < tx.length; i++) {
        tx[i].setAttribute('style', 'height:' + (tx[i].scrollHeight) + 'px;overflow-y:hidden;');
      }
    }
```

...

```
    <textarea 
      className='comment-area-responsive' 
      name='title' 
      placeholder='What do you think?' 
      value={text} onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)} 
      required>
    </textarea>
```

Here's a [working Stackblitz to play around](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2f97mo).

Comment: it still doesn't work after changing everything you said, looks like the `OnInput()`function is not run. `onChange` is added not for this purpose but for managing the state of react.

Comment: Updated the answer with a Stackblitz link for React

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies with your textarea.

```
<textarea 
  className='comment-area-responsive' 
  name='title' 
  placeholder='What do you think?' 
  value={text} onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)} 
  required
/>
```

The `textarea` tag must be implicitly closed.

```
<textarea 
  className='comment-area-responsive' 
  name='title' 
  placeholder='What do you think?' 
  value={text} onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)} 
  required
></textarea>
```

Can you try and see if this fixes your issue?

Comment: it still doesn't work somehow, looks like the `OnInput()`function is not run

Comment: I tried typing `tx` in the console and this variable does contain the textarea inside it

Comment: I found out that the `for` loop is not called as well unless I made it `for (var i = 0; i < tx.length; i++)`. It's strange because `tx.length` does show `2` in the browser console when there are 2 textareas on the page.

Comment: But when I tried alert the length `alert(tx.length);` in the for loop it alerts `0` in the browser instead.